# Create a listener to detect the presence of an alert popup (using Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, listener, alert

I need to create a listener that checks whether an alert is present or not. This alert pops up randomly while navigating the site, asking for credentials, and if it receives no response it causes the driver to timeout. We're currently entering the credentials by hand to allow the code to continue, but later this will run without being monitored so this won't work much longer.

Answer (score 0):

Custom class implements webdrivereventlistener
Override find
Wait for element (from method arg)
If element not present
Driver.switch.to.alert != null
Alert accept or enter auth whatever

Main class
Eventfiringwebdriver driver instantiate

Create earlier custom class instance listener
Driver.register above custom class 
do your stuff for every find listener activates and check for alert
Driver.unregister
You might want to check cypress where in listeners to alerts are handled easily